# Specify session cookie in RAML

Tags: rest, yaml, session-cookies, raml

I am documenting an API, that requires some endpoints for the request to be authenticated by a session cookie. This cookie is set after the user logs in using a form that POSTs a username and a password to the server.

Is there a way to specify this using the RAML 1.0 protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing specific for cookies in the spec, at the moment. However you can model it with `headers` and `securitySchemes`.

The example below creates a custom `securityScheme` requiring a `Cookie` header and describes to add a 'JSESSIONID' value. This can be changed to suit your use-case.

The first resource describes a 'login' endpoint that describes a header named 'Set-Cookie' with an example value will be returned and must be sent on future requests.

The second resource then is `securedBy` the custom 'cookie-auth' security scheme.

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Example cookie auth
version: 1.0

securitySchemes:
  cookie-auth:
    description: |
      custom authentication scheme for JSESSIONID cookie.
    type:
      x-custom
    describedBy:
      headers:
        Cookie:
          description: |
           JSESSIONID
          type: string
/login:
  post:
    body:
      application/json:
    description: |
      The session ID is returned in a cookie named `JSESSIONID`. You need to include this cookie in subsequent requests.
    headers:
      Set-Cookie:
        type: string
        example: JSESSIONID=abcde12345; Path=/; HttpOnly
    responses:
      201:
        body:
          application/json:
            # ...
/someprotectedresource:
  securedBy: cookie-auth
  get:
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to implement it this way then. I was actually hoping that there would be an easier, more intuitive way of doing this. After all, such an authentication strategy can't be that rare. Hopefully, a better method is going to be added in the next RAML version.